# Can't save Excel file with win32com.client

Tags: python, excel, win32com

When I try to save the file, it doesn't save and fails.

I get the error:

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'Save method of Application class failed', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Some other posts seem to be pretty old and not relevant.

I saw a post saying to use `SaveAs()` but that errors out and says `AttributeError: <unknown>.SaveAs. Did you mean: 'Save'?`

My code:

```
import os, os.path
import win32com.client

# path = (r'C:\Users\christiansanchez\Downloads\')

if os.path.exists("test_macro.xlsm"):
    xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    xl.Workbooks.Open(os.path.abspath("test_macro.xlsm"))
    xl.Application.Run("test_macro.xlsm!module1.test_macrob")
    xl.Application.Save("test_macro.xlsm")
    xl.Application.Quit("test_macro.xlsm")
else:
    print("error")
```

Comment: You want to call `.Save` on a `Workbook` object, not the `Application`. Btw, I don't think `Quit` has any parameters.

Comment: Also, `xl.Application` is superfluous. `xl` already refers to an Application object, just use `xl.Workbooks.Open` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the comments, assign a variable to the opened workbook, and call `Save()` on that:

```
import os, os.path
import win32com.client

# path = (r'C:\Users\christiansanchez\Downloads\')

if os.path.exists('test_macro.xlsm'):
    xl = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
    wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(os.path.abspath('test_macro.xlsm'))
    xl.Run('test_macrob')
    wb.Save()
    xl.Quit()
else:
    print("error")
```

Notes:

- Macro names are at global scope in Excel, so unless you have two sheets with the same macro name open you don't need to fully qualify the macro name.
- The variable `xl` already refers to an Application object: you don't need `xl.Application`